# Boost function "tuple_list_of" cannot be resolved

Tags: c++, boost, ubuntu-12.04

**EDIT TO ANSWER COMMENTS AND CLOSE QUESTION:**

There was actually no problem: the line makes eclipse analyzer to show that "ghost error", but g++ can process it correctly. I suffered this problem previously when using boost and some of its convoluted template meta-programming constructs.

I didn't noticed it because it was mixed with other errors. Sorry for the silly question, and thank you for your help.

P.S.: note for me-- do not try to solve these problems after 10 hours programming

**-- END OF EDIT --**

I have boost library (version 1.52) installed in a 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) system.

I followed the standard procedure found in the [installation instructions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/bbv2/installation.html), which involve executing a "bootstrap" script, and then invoking b2. Everything fine: no errors and no skipped targets.

I found that the function `boost::assign::tuple_list_of` "couldn't be resolved" according to g++. I use it in the following line (the asignee can be safely ignored):

```
#include <vector>
#include "boost/assign/list_of.hpp"

std::vector<boost::tuple<int,int> > vec = boost::assign::tuple_list_of(0,0)(2,2)(4,0)(6,2);
```

I took a look at file [include]boost/assign/list_of.hpp, and the ONLY reference to "tuple_list_of" is in the following macro:

```
#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n) \
    template< class U, BOOST_ASSIGN_PARAMS1(n) > \
    inline assign_detail::generic_list< tuple<U, BOOST_ASSIGN_PARAMS4(n)> > \
    tuple_list_of(U u, BOOST_ASSIGN_PARAMS2_NO_REF(n) ) \
    { \
        return assign_detail::generic_list< tuple<U, BOOST_ASSIGN_PARAMS4(n)> >()( tuple<U,BOOST_ASSIGN_PARAMS4(n)>( u, BOOST_ASSIGN_PARAMS3(n) )); \
    } \
```

Any clue about this behavior? Am I missing some "fundamental" step?

Comment: What is the full compiler error message?

Comment: Works for me; I'd try getting the preprocessed source and checking if anything suspicious shows up.